# jquery Auto search result is not updating the value to textbox after clicking

Tags: ajax, jquery

Below code display the list populated from database(DB code is not included).     If I click on the search results, then the selected option will not show in textbox. Help please.

Below code works fine to show list of options from Database while typing characters. The issue is it will not show the selected drop down option into textbox.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Auto Complete</title>
<script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
$('#suggestions').hide();
} else {
$.post("states.jsp", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
if(data.length >0) {
$('#suggestions').show();
$('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
}
});
}
}
function fill(thisValue) {
$('#inputString').val(thisValue);
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 13px;
color: #000;
}
h3 {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.suggestionsBox {
position: relative;
left: 260px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #7845DD;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
border: 2px solid #000;
color: #fff;
}
.suggestionList {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.suggestionList li {
margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
padding: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.suggestionList li:hover {
background-color: #DD45CD;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form>
<div> <h3><font color="red">Indian States</states></font></h3>
<br /> Enter India State Name to see autocomplete
<input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString"
onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
</div>
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
<div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>



<%
String name=request.getParameter("queryString");
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost", "user", "password");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
//Add the data into the database
String sql = "SELECT EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID, EMP_FNAME, EMP_LNAME FROM UAP_EMPLOYEE where EMP_FNAME     LIKE '%"+name+"%' OR EMP_LNAME LIKE '%"+name+"%';"; 
Statement stm = con.createStatement();
stm.executeQuery(sql);
ResultSet rs= stm.getResultSet();
while (rs.next ()){
out.println("<li onclick='fill("+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+");>"+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+"    </i>");
}}catch(Exception e){
out.println("Exception is ;"+e);
}
%>
```

Comment: I hope nobody else has to use/read your code when it's indented like that (ie. not at all). **Format your code properly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

`$('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);`

you are setting some html that I assume consists of a list of `div` tags with your auto-suggestions. If you want the user to be able to click on the list, you need to have a `click` handler attached to the suggestions that loads the value. Like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#autoSuggestionsList div").on("click", function() {
      //put your click actions here.. load the textbox, hide the list
   });
}
```

The `on` command is live, meaning it will automatically be bound to elements that are loaded dynamically.

**EDIT**

Since you're using `li` instead of `div`, change the above to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#autoSuggestionsList li").on("click", function() {
      fill($(this).text());
   });
}
```

**EDIT 2**

In the new code you added, this line is incorrect

```
out.println("<li onclick='fill("+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+");>"+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+"    </i>");
```

It will produce incorrect HTML/Javascript that looks like this:

`<li onclick='fill(some text);>some text</i>`

Your code should look like this:

```
out.println("<li onclick='fill(\""+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+"\");'>"+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+"    </li>");
```

It will produce the following correct HTML/JavascriptL

`<li onclick='fill("some text");'>some text</li>`

Comment: I am using the fill() method in JSP file that is used to retrieve database values. I updated it below  the HTML code.

Comment: I don't recommend sending the function in with the new code. Since you're using jQuery, utilize `on` like in my new example. I also noticed a typo in the new code you added: you open with `li` and close with `i`. Add the `$(document).ready...` code anywhere inside your `script` tag.

Comment: For what it's worth, `on` used to be `live` in older versions of the jQuery framework. But `live` is now deprecated, and `on` is preferable.

Comment: Thanks for showing the typo. Above code didn't help me. Once I click on the values from the dropdown list, I get below error.                     "NASH is undefined".   NASH is a value from database.

Comment: Ha.. that helped. changing the code to click='fill(\""+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+"\");'>"+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+"    </li>");  resolved the issue. Thanks for your help friend..

Comment: No problem. If the solution did it for you, please mark it as the answer. Thank you!